# Is it possible to put value from linux pipe into curl querystring param?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a numeric output from command, let's say:

```
 sh -c 'exit 1' ; echo $?
```

or

```
bc <<< "1 + 1"
```

And I need to send it in GET request via curl, like http://example.com/?value=1

I've tried this:

```
sh -c 'exit 1' ; echo $? | curl -G -d @- http://example.com/
```

but it just got param with a name `1` and `empty` value.

I know I can do something like:

`` result=`sh -c 'exit 129' ; echo $?` | curl -G -d value=${result} http://example.com ``

but I'd like to keep the first part of command unchanged and modify only part after pipe. Is it possible?

Comment: `sh -c 'exit 1' ;  curl -G "http://example.com/?value=$?"`

Comment: If for some weird reason the "1" must come through a pipe: `sh -c 'exit 1'; echo $? | { read ecode; curl -G "http://example.com/?value=$ecode; }`

Comment: @jordanm it does not have to be an exit-code, I need to pass any result, for example, `bc << "1 + 1"`

Comment: @jordanm second option works fine on macos but doesn't work on ubuntu

Comment: I assume you mean in `bash` vs ubuntu's `sh` (dash shell)? What error do you get?

Comment: @jordanm I'm looking for cross-nix solution. No error, just empty value:

`root@srv:~# sh -c 'exit 19'; echo $? | read ecode`
`root@srv:~# echo $ecode
`

Comment: `curl "http://example.com/?value=$(false; echo $?)"`

Comment: @iscfrc  it does not have to be an exit-code, I need to pass any numeric result, for example, bc << "1 + 1"

Comment: @AlexZaitsev Replace the interior of `$()` with any command you like.

Comment: @iscfrc I'd like to keep the first part of the command unchanged and modify only part after pipe.

Comment: @AlexZaitsev `bc <<<1+1 | curl "http://example.com/?value=$(cat)"`

Comment: @iscfrc what is $(cat)?

Comment: @AlexZaitsev `cat` without arguments just reads from its input (in this case, the pipeline), and sends the data straight through to its output. `$(somecommand)` captures the output of `somecommand`, and basically includes it in the command at that point. Put 'em together, and it inserts the command's input (i.e. "1") into the command at that point.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `bc <<<1+1 | curl "http://example.com/?value=$(cat)"` just hangs on macos

Comment: @AlexZaitsev Are you doing that under bash or zsh (the new default interactive under recent versions of macOS)? It works fine for me under bash, but for some reason freezes under zsh. I don't know why, so I'll investigate and see if I can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @AlexZaitsev It looks like part of the problem is that with that construction in zsh, the `cat` command isn't getting its standard input from the pipe, it's keeping the previous context's input (probably the terminal). But there's something else weird going on that I don't understand. Maybe it's best to avoid this construct...

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution I found:

```
sh -c 'exit 129'; echo $? | xargs -I '{}' curl -G "http://example.com?value={}";
```